# Возможно ли скрыть текст своего сайта от видеосъёмок?

Tags: javascript, текст, видео, веб-сайт, камера

Возможно ли скрыть текст(например своего вебсайта) для видеокамер и камер смартфонов? То есть чтобы снятый текст на камеру не был виден в снятом видео.

Есть идея, использовать моргание текста на вебсайте на определённый частоте не соотвествующей частоте обновления кадров в секунду, но мне кажется что это совсем бредовая идея.
И всё-таки, возможно ли это сделать?

Comment: Ежели честно, не столько идея моргания текста бредовая, сколько бредова сама идея защиты сайта от съемки на видео.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Можете сделать следующее: Попросить доступ к камере, если его нет или пользователь отказал в доступе, то сайт не показывает. Если же он дал доступ, то смотреть на картину и с помощью ИИ распозновать взял ли он в руки камеру (не важно смартфона или профессиональную). Если взял, то не показывать, если всё хорошо то показывать. Если же ИИ не может понять что на картинке вообще, то не показывать ничего. Для защиты от таких случаев как например, если специально ухудшил фокус, или закрыл камеру чем-то чтобы ничего не было видно

Comment: для съемки видео камера не обязана быть в руках ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯. По картинке - невозможно узнать работает камера или нет. Не у всех девайсов, с которых просматриваются сайты, вообще камера есть

Comment: @Grundy Именно потому что не у всех есть я и сказал "если его нет или пользователь отказал в доступе, то сайт не показывает") Работает камера или нет не волнует, факт того что взял камеру в руки вполне хвататет уже что-то подозревать))

Comment: @Grundy если не в руки, можно впрнципе посмотреть видна ли камера. Правда и это наверное можно обмануть поставив камеру под нужным углом)

Comment: камеры бывают разные ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: На то и нужен ИИ и нужна хорошая база для распознавания камеры, но это уже технические детали) Я понимаю что и ИИ на данный момент можно легко обмануть, но это всё что я могу предложить как самый костыльный вариант) А так я полносью согласен с @NoSkill )

Comment: ну тут ИИ не поможет ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯